# XML parsing Error in android?

Tags: android, xml

This is my XML format got as response from web service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



 <HaendlerLeistungen>
  <leistung id="20" name="Autowerkstätte" />
  <leistung id="42" name="Barankauf" />
  <leistung id="14" name="B-Schein Schulungen" />
  <leistung id="41" name="Chrom" />
  <leistung id="24" name="Ersatzteile" />
  <leistung id="13" name="Fahrschule" />
  <leistung id="44" name="Fahrwerk" />
  <leistung id="23" name="Finanzierung" />

  </HaendlerLeistungen>
```

I use the following code to prepare Document object,`

```
private Document getDomElement(String xml){
....
...
             InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

     ...
     .....
            return doc;
    }
public Document convertStreamToString() throws IOException {
     ....
     ....
    try {

    url = new URL("Service URL to fetch corresponding reponse");

    urlConn = url.openConnection();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {



    }
    InputStream is = urlConn.getInputStream();
    if (is != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Tight Weight"+sb.toString());
        return getDomElement(sb.toString());
    } else {        
        return getDomElement("");
    }
}`
```

THe string log prints entire XML correctly, but when i try to prepare Document object it throws following error

```
02-14 19:35:46.360: E/Error:(14863): PI must not start with xml (position:unknown xm@1:5 in java.io.StringReader@44eab4a0)
```

i don`t know whether problem in my XML or parsing. If any one knows the solution, please the help me out.

Note: the response contain german characters;

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there are no weird characters (e.g. BOM) oder Whitespace before the XML preamble (`<?xml ...?>`)?

And what's the `Content-Type` header? Could you send us the URL the XML is from?

Try to remove the whole preamble...

Comment: The white space was my problem.